# Why there is a difference between same components of 2 parallel planes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

[image]

[image]

In this context the author is deriving the net outflow through 2 surfaces.to do so he is calculating the difference between x components ofthe vector V.

[image]

so now my question is here the 2 surface are parallel to each other and have same area so their respective x components should be same.so why there is a difference?

Comment: The cube is fixed in space with surface normals along the 3 coordinates, to ensure water flow components are along these. A cube is chosen to ensure there is no area effects on calculation. But the flow velocity changes changes from point to point and from surface to surface. Then you can relate such changes to forces of pressure and shear on the surfaces of the cube.

Comment: In Eqns. 2-4, the planes are not taken to be parallel.